# Dynamic number of text fields when a value from dropdown is selected in Magento 2 system configuration backend

Tags: magento2, system-config

I have one drop down with fixed set of values lets call 1 to 5. when i select any number that many number of textboxes should be visible in the admin system configuration in magento 2.

for example. if i select 3 from drop down then i want to show 3 text boxes just below the dropdown. if i select 1 from drop down then one text box should be shown.

please help me how can i achieve this in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

Suppose your field like

```
<field id="test" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <source_model>VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Dropdown</source_model>
</field>
```

And your dropdown has following value

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;

class Dropdown implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $options[] = ['value' => '1', 'label' => 'One'];
        $options[] = ['value' => '2', 'label' => 'Two'];
        $options[] = ['value' => '3', 'label' => 'Three'];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Now added following code where you want to depends

```
<depends>
    <field id="test">2</field>
</depends>
```

So for example:

```
<field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Title</label>
    <depends>
        <field id="test">2</field>
    </depends>
</field>
```

In above example, title field will be visible if **test** value is 2.